# Unable to convert runtime connection string to its design-time equivalent Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012

I am using MySql Connector 6.8.3 (the latest).

I am using Visual Studio 2012 so this is not the known issue in Visual Studio 2013 as this SO solution provides:
[Unable to convert runtime connection string to its design-time equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983270/unable-to-convert-runtime-connection-string-to-its-design-time-equivalent)

I am using this connection string:

```
<add name="db_uTextEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/uTextModel.csdl|res://*/uTextModel.ssdl|res://*/uTextModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=username;password=password;database=db_uText_v1&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

So I had an older version of the MySql .NET Connector, I upgraded to version 6.8.3. A developer told me that this upgrade doesn't always actually work even though it seems like it does. Uninstalling MySql .NET Connector and reinstalling fixed my issue.