# Unable to update EntityFramework models from MySQL database in Visual Studio 2015 RC

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2015, mysql-connector, mysql.data

My organization upgraded from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2015 RC a couple months ago, and we only just now attempted to update some of our existing "db-first" EntityFramework models from our MySQL database. When doing so, we received the following error.

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred while attempting to update from the database. The exception message is: 'Unable to convert runtime connection string to its design-time equivalent. The libraries required to enable Visual Studio to communicate with the database for design purposes (DDEX provider) are not installed for provider 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient'.

A quick SO search for this error produced [this result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983270/unable-to-convert-runtime-connection-string-to-its-design-time-equivalent) from November of 2013 (specifically in reference to VS 2013)...

> Apparently MySql and Visual Studio 2013 don't work together yet.
>
> Here is a link on the MySql forums: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,594798,600466#msg-600466
>
> You'll probably need to wait for the next release of the MySql connector.

Does that mean this is likely a comparable issue, and we just have to wait it out until a new MySql.Data client is available that is compatible with VS 2015? Or is it possible that some other cause is to blame (perhaps a bug in VS 2015 RC)?

We're on the latest stable versions of Entity Framework (6.1.3), MySql.Data (6.9.6) and MySql.Data.Entity (6.9.6).

Especially curious to hear if anyone else has stumbled across this issue with VS 2015 RC in particular.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What worked for me was to update the visual studio plugin, available here:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/

Comment: The "MySQL for Visual Studio" plugin fixed it (v1.2.4, at the time of my install). Nice find! Interesting that this wasn't necessary before (or maybe we've just been running an outdated version), but at least it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please update your VS 2015 from RC to RTM, update the nuget packages by running the following command:

update-package

This will get all latest stable nuget package in VS 2015.

Let me know if this fix your issue.

Comment: We recently updated from VS 2015 RC to RTM, and that did not resolve the issue. We're also already on the latest stable nuget packages for Entity Framework and the MySql data connectors.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I installed Visual Studio right after Mysql installing. Therefore Mysql Visual Studio components weren't installed.

To fix that just open [MySQL for VS install](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/) and pick "Change"

Then check components for target Visual Stadio version

[image]
[image]

Comment: This worked for me. If anyone needs more of a pointer on where to find that, you don't need to download the installer again.. Close VS and open your windows settings and go to apps, or open the start menu and type "add or remove programs". After that, a list should load and you can search for "MySQL for Visual Studio" and click "Modify" then you should see the wizard popup, click Next, then Change, and follow the above.

Answer (score -1):

My reputation isn't high enough to leave a comment but this could help someone that ends up on this page. My case was similar to neustart47's however I tried to install the components through mysql installer - community, which failed complaining that VS wasn't installed (or something along those lines), which it was. So make sure to use the stand alone installer and not the mysql community installer. Why this even is a problem, I don't know.